# pass JSON object from php to javascript in the same script

Tags: php, javascript, json

This is probably an easy question, but I haven't been able to find a complete and specific answer. I create a json object in php with json_encode(), now i just need to get that object in javascript and parse it out. I wanted to do it in the same script, but I can do it another way if need be.

How do i get at this object from javascript?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, could you expand exactly on what are you trying to do ? Cheers.

Comment: How about some code? With comments.

Comment: yeah, i guess its simple enough that im not being clear. I have create d JSON with php. I'm just not sure what i do with the object now, what do i call to be able to parse it in JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

$stuff = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var stuff = <?php print json_encode($stuff); ?>;
  alert(stuff.a); // 1
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $x = array(1,2,3);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = <?php echo json_encode($x);
</script>
```

would produce

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = [1,2,3];
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's all in the same script you and just `echo` it into the page.

```
$my_json = json_encode($some_object);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo "var my_js_obj = $my_json;";
echo '</script>';
```

Now after that javascript can access the `my_js_obj` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
<script>
    var jsVar = <?php echo json_encode($phpData); ?>;
</script>
```

You simply echo the JSON string, since that is a syntax understood by JavaScript (JSON = JavaScript Object Notation).

Answer (score 2):

Lets say your php looks like this:

```
<?php
    $myData = json_encode($some_data);
?>
```

Then in your javascript you can just assign that php variable to an object like this by echoing the value of that variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myObj = <?=$myData;?>;
</script>
```